# Equivalence Relation $f \sim g$ if $f(k/10) = g(k/10)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $0 ≤ k ≤ 10$

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

A question from *Real Analysis and Applications* by Davidson & Donsig follows.
[image]

Though not specified in the question, I am presuming that $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (I suspect (e) is suggestive of this). My rough ideas as to the solution to parts (a)-(e) of this question follow:

- (a) That this is an equivalence relation is trivial. For instance, as to the property of transitivity, $f \sim g$ and $g 
  \sim h$ would mean that $f(k/10) = g(k/10) = h(k/10)$, whence $f \sim h$.
- (b) I suspect the equivalence class of an element $f \in C[0,1]$ consists of all functions equal to $f$ at 11 distinct points, viz., at $0, 0.1, 0.2, ... 1.$ So $[f] = \{g \in C[0, 1]: g(0) = f(0), g(0.1) = f(0.1), ..., g(1) = f(1)\}$
- (c) I suspect that it suffices to consider two representatives $f_1, f_2 \in [f]$ and $g_1, g_2 \in [g]$ and to show that the result of the operation acting on $f_1$ and $g_1$ would be ~ to that acting on $f_2$ and $g_2$. But, this is indeed so: $(f_1 + g_1)(k/10) = f_1(k/10) + g_1(k/10) = f_2(k/10) + g_2(k/10) = (f_2 + g_2)(k/10)$ at every $k$, since $f_1 \sim f_2$ and $g_1 \sim g_2$.
- (d) Likewise, I suspect we can consider two representatives $f_1, f_2 \in [f]$ and show that in multiplying $t$ to $f_1$ and $f_2$, we get that $tf_1, tf_2 \in [tf]$? But, this would indeed be so, as $f_1(k/10) = f_2(k/10) \Rightarrow (tf_1)(k/10) = (tf_2)(k/10)$ at every $k$.
- (e) I am not certain that my solution thus far would make this statement true. In particular, in considering the way in which I defined equivalence classes in (b), I do not believe that their union would result in a vector space of dimension 11...?

I would wish to know whether my solutions to (a)-(e) are on the right track or completely off; and in particular, how (e) might be proven.

Comment: You are on the right tracks from (a) to (d) ; and you only need to convince yourself that the set of all equivalence classes that you made explicit in (b), does indeed have the structure of a real vector space (thanks to (c) and (d)) of dimension 11. Intuitively, dimension is the minimal number of scalars necessary to specify any vector of your space. How many real scalars do you need in order to specify one equivalence class as described in (b) ?

Comment: For (e), consider the natural map $C[0,1]/\sim\to\Bbb R^{11}$ you already defined.